# Strange behavior of css, fixes after refresh

Tags: css, positioning, browser-refresh

I'm trying to build a page where users browse certain flash games, and I create thumbnail `<div>`s for them. They work nicely at first, but when I click one game, and return to the browse page,
the text coincides with the image, when I refresh, it becomes ok.

Wrong version: (after returning back)
[image]

Right version: (at start and after refresh)
[image]

There is no JavaScript running, so I do not change the styles of elements. The `<div>`'s with the problem has .css codes like:

```
div.game_side_texts
{
clear:right;
float:top; 
max-height:80%;
}

img.gamethumb
{
height:80%;
}

div.game_img_div
{
float:left;
margin-right:2%;
min-width:30%;
}

.game_thumbnail_div /* the div that contains everything */
{
float:left;

width:40%;
height:20%;

margin-top:6%;
margin-right:1%;

padding-bottom:3%;
}
```

So what could be the problem? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please post yout HTML too. Also if you could create a jsfiddle replicating the problem that would be great. Last resort would be a link to your site.

Comment: At first glance: there is no such thing as `float: top;`

Comment: @watson Logically, that would be a quite useful property (well `float: bottom`).

Comment: @OP Your problem most probably has to do with `width: 40%;` on `.game_thumbnail_div` but you should make a jsFiddle (google it) for me to make sure.

Comment: @watson I was just about to ask "What does float:top do?" Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @everybody I tried it and when it worked I thought it was correct :D.
Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xbycA/4/

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `.game_thumbnail_div` has a width and height that is too small. Either remove them or make the dimensions at least 286 x 140. Also, `float:top` doesn't do anything. I know you mentioned that you tried it and it worked but I promise you it's not needed.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xbycA/5/)